# Spring service and Spring web app in one

Tags: spring, web-services, rest, spring-mvc, web

I'm making a Spring RESTFUL service and i wonder. Can I make a Spring RESTFUL service combine with a web app in a project. If it is possible, how to configure it?

.

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Try to be more explicit else you'll not find the answer.

Comment: please give more details on your question. Of course you can make REST service within an web app project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes that is possible to combine with web-app

for example your controller package into your restful controller also work 
that is possible to crud operation via restful web service.